# Wordpress can't see linked mysql container on IBM Bluemix with Docker compose

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, docker-compose

I have a simple docker-compose.yml (wp image is based on ibmjstart/wp-bluemix-container, db image is mariadb)

```
db:
  image: registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/foo/db
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql

wp:
   image: registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/foo/wp
   links:
     - db:mysql
   ports:
     - 80:80
```

after executing `docker compose up -d` I get

```
error: missing WORDPRESS_DB_HOST and MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP environment variables
  Did you forget to --link some_mysql_container:mysql or set an external db
  with -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=hostname:port?
```

As you can see, the db container is linked.

When I do the same without docker-compose, using

```
$ cf ic run -v mysql-vol:/var/lib/mysql --name wpdb  -d registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/foo/db    
$ cf ic run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw  -v web-files:/var/www/html/ --link wpdb:mysql  -d registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/foo/wp
```

Everything works well.

---

I do export docker variables after `cf ic login`

More info:

```
root@vps:~/test/compose# docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.7.0, build 0d7bf73
root@vps:~/test/compose# docker --version
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
root@vps:~/test/compose# cf --version
cf version 6.15.0+fa1bfe2-2016-01-13
root@vps:~/test/compose# cf ic --version
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
```

---

UPDATE: As I understand, this problem is caused by the naming:

This docker-compose.yml throws an error

```
db:
  image: registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/foo/db
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
  container_name:
    wpdb
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql

wp:
   image: registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/foo/wp
   links:
     - wpdb:mysql
   ports:
     - 80:80
```

ERROR: Service "wp" has a link to service "wpdb" which does not exist.

However, if you name the service and container the same, the syntax is ok.

```
db:
  image: registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/foo/db
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
  container_name:
    db
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql

wp:
   image: registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/foo/wp
   links:
     - db:mysql
   ports:
     - 80:80
```

Although the syntax is OK and the container is linked, the wordpress container logs this

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10    
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Is this a bug in Bluemix? Looks like a /etc/hosts/ related problem

Sorry for a long post :)

Comment: Could you please let me know the environment you are running your containers? `cf ic info | grep Environment`

Comment: @AlexdaSilva `Environment name         : prod-lon02-vizio1`

Answer (score 2):

@bartimar Yes, the problem is related to the `/etc/hosts` file. It needs to have an entry for the db container, but it is not creating it.

I can recreate your problem in the `prod-lon02-vizio1` environment, but it works fine in the `prod-lon02-kraken1` environment.

My recommendation if for you to manually migrate to the `prod-lon02-kraken1` environment to use docker-compose.yml with IBM containers. All environments will be automatically migrated on May 25th anyway.

To migrate simply run the following command:

```
$ cf ic reprovision
```

Please note that your images are migrated to new environment, **but all your running containers are deleted and you will have to recreate them in the new environment.** So use this option with caution.

For more details check the link below:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2016/03/24/new-deployment-architecture-for-containers/?linkId=22660520

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean all containers will be automatically deleted on May 25th?

Comment: That's my understanding per the last paragraph in the document link I added to the answer, however if you do the migration before May 25th then your containers will not be deleted as you will already be in the new environment.